# How to define filterToQuery prop of ReferenceInput to use its own value and value of another input

Tags: admin-on-rest

My use case:

I have got a form and two `ReferenceInput`s with `AutocompleteInput` on them.

I choose a user in the first `ReferenceInput`, then I want to query the books of the selected user from the server to the next `ReferenceInput`.

How to define the `filterToQuery` property in this situation?

```
filterToQuery={searchText => ({ 'q[name_cont]': searchText, q[user_id_eq]: ??? })}
```

Answer (score 0):

[aor-dependent-input](https://github.com/marmelab/aor-dependent-input/) might help you with that. You'll find an example close to what you want in the [README](https://github.com/marmelab/aor-dependent-input/#re-rendering-the-dependentinput-children-when-the-values-of-the-dependencies-change)

Comment: If aor-dependent-input works then it would be the ideal solution for this question.

Comment: I must say I haven't found time to test it with the latest aor release. Please let me know if you encounter any problems

Answer (score -1):

You will need to write a custom redux connected component that will wrap your referenceInput and provide it filter values based on selected value in state.

You can access the current data from state.admin.form.*'YOURFORMNAME'* redux form also provides some utility functions that you can use to access the value in the other component

https://redux-form.com/7.0.4/docs/api/selectors.md/

```
class ConnectedInput extends Component {


    componentWillRecieveProps = (nextProps, currentProps) => {
        if (nextProps.userName !== currentProps.userName) {
            //reset state to set the the filter to query property based on new props and forcing a rerendering which will make the db call
        } 
    }

    render() {
        return (
              <ReferenceInput filterToQuery={this.state.filter}>
                   <DisplayComponent />
              </ReferenceInput>
         )
    }

    mapStateToProps = () => {
        const userName = //get from the state
        return userName
    }
}
```